# restore stdout and stderr after sigpipe

Tags: c++, bash, pipe, signals

When I do

```
executable 2>&1 | asan_symbolize.py
```

where `executable` is a C++ executable where I pipe both stdout and stderr to the `asan_symbolize.py` (some prettyfier for leak-sanitzer and address-sanitizer)

when I send `SIGINT` to the whole process group, `asan_symbolize.py` quits and `executable` receives a (as a second signal) a `SIGPIPE`. Because the pipe closes quickly the signal handling output of `executable` to `stdout` and `stderr` disappears because the `stdout` and `stderr` are already destroyed.

Is there a solution (something like `tee` inbetween? ) to make `stdout` and `stderr` be redirected to the terminal again after receiving `SIGPIPE` in `executable`?

Maybe I need a different solution which I dont know currently, I am out of my luck...

Comment: trap the signal and redirect them.

Comment: I don't have time to provide a full answer but you could create a shell script to run the above commands and use the shell `trap` feature to catch the signal.

Comment: but that trap will first execute when the command is finished, or would you run the command in the background and trap the signal but what and how to redirect I dont know

Comment: So you want to stop the asan.py but continue to see data from the executable ?

Comment: yes, (while the executable is cleaning up)

Answer (score 1):

dirty trick that can work for ttys (to reconstruct stdout and stderr from stdin). Inside a signal handler for SIGPIPE

```
void sigpipe_handler(int s)
{
  dup2 (0, 1);
  dup2 (0, 2);
}
```